# Is the hadith of "drinking wine and call it by another name" referring to soft drinks?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, alcohol

There is a hadith in [Sunan Abi Dawud 3688](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/20)

Narrated Abdur Rahman ibn Ghanam: Malik ibn Abu Maryam said: Abdur Rahman ibn Ghanam entered upon us and we discussed tila' and he said: Abu Malik al-Ashari told me that he heard the Messenger of Allah صلی ‌اللہ ‌علیہ ‌وسلم say: Some of my people will assuredly drink wine calling it by another name.

Does this referring to todays soft drinks like cola, Pepsi etc. Cause they contain little amount of alcohol. if not then what this hadith referring to?

Comment: What it refers to is perhaps opinion based it may or may not have occurred yet. Arguing that it is soft drinks is a very flimsy argument since the hadith is about calling wine by another name: sodas are not wine, not made from wine, and do not have any intoxicating effects like wine. Trace amounts of ethanol are due to natural fermentation and may also be found in fruit juices and baked products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assalamualaikum, firstly, i just wanna say that it is very unlikely that this hadith is referring to soft drinks because i have not heard of any scholar who has said that soft drinks are haram and also because there is nothing haram about soft drinks, it could be called bad for health at best . Secondly, this hadith could be referring to the many new types of alcoholic drinks which were not present at the time of the Prophet(pbuh) or perhaps this event has not occured as of yet. Finally as the brother has mentioned in the above comment that "Trace amounts of ethanol are due to natural fermentation" and such amounts are also found in products such as vanilla essence but no matter how much vanilla cake (which includes vanilla essence) one eats he will not be intoxicated hence it is halal. Similarly no matter how much coke one drinks it will not intoxicate him so it is also halal(i do not know much about the science of why vanilla essence or coke do not intoxicate in small amounts and so i will not get into it). For a more detailed explanation of the rulings and the science behind the topic u can refer to here: 1 https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/102749 2 https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/177030 and Allah knows best. JazakAllah